# Could this be done another way

Tags: grep

Hello I am trying to learn grep regex (not sure what you would call it). I figured this would be a good way to start.

Below is the data. I want to extract the file names and Inode numbers.

```
  File: vimt
  Size: 24              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 3166374     Links: 2
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    test)   Gid: ( 1000/    test)
Access: 2022-02-20 00:29:43.732363386 -0500
Modify: 2022-02-20 00:29:40.516363443 -0500
Change: 2022-02-20 00:29:40.516363443 -0500
 Birth: 2022-02-20 00:28:41.196364492 -0500
  File: vimhard
  Size: 24              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 3166374     Links: 2
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    test)   Gid: ( 1000/    test)
Access: 2022-02-20 00:29:43.732363386 -0500
Modify: 2022-02-20 00:29:40.516363443 -0500
Change: 2022-02-20 00:29:40.516363443 -0500
 Birth: 2022-02-20 00:28:41.196364492 -0500
  File: vimhard1
  Size: 24              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 3166372     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    test)   Gid: ( 1000/    test)
Access: 2022-02-20 00:34:39.312358161 -0500
Modify: 2022-02-20 00:34:39.312358161 -0500
Change: 2022-02-20 00:34:39.312358161 -0500
 Birth: 2022-02-20 00:34:39.312358161 -0500
```

This is what i was able to come up with

```
stat vimt vimhard vimhard1 | grep -o  "File.*\|Inode.*[[:digit:]]\{7\}"
```

It did give me what i was looking for

```
File: vimt
Inode: 3166374
File: vimhard
Inode: 3166374
File: vimhard1
Inode: 3166372
```

I am just wondering if this is a fluke because I am still surprised I was able to get the data I wanted or is there a better way to pull it out that is more reliable?. I just don't trust what i came up with.

I did have a really fun time doing this even though it seems very simple.

Comment: If this is what you want, this is close to perfect! Are there other ways, sure there are. But this is a nice `grep`! I would slightly modify it into `grep -o "File: *\|Inode: *[[:digit:]]\+"` or enable extended regular expressions and write it as `grep -Eo "File: *|Inode: *[[:digit:]]+"`

Comment: @kvantour Awesome! Thank you, I will keep your modified way in mind when I practice with grep again!

Comment: be aware that the original `grep` can give unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
grep -Eo  "(File|Inode):[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+" file
## or
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "File:" || $i == "Inode:") { print $i" "$(i+1) } }' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/TrIJKS).

The `grep` solution extracts (`-o` outputs matches only) substrings that start with `File` or `Inode` (see `(File|Inode)`), then `:`, then zero or more whitespaces (`[[:space:]]*`), and then one or more non-whitespace chars (`[^[:space:]]+`).

The `awk` solution iterates over the whitespace-separated fields on each line and if it finds `File:` or `Inode:` field, it prints the concatenated values of the current and next fields.